# ZingGrid Modal record display function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to archive modal of record banner as display on the home page, 3 dots button https://www.zinggrid.com/

Following the guide in https://www.zinggrid.com/docs/api/methods/reference#zg-dialog

// Customize delete record dialog
zgRef.customizeDialog('view-info', {
cancel: "Don't do it!!!",
confirm: "Okay",
label: "End this record"
});

I made this change in JS
const zgRef = document.querySelector('zing-grid');

but the model record info still not display, what else should i change?